# why does xamarin suddenly not let me deploy to iOS devices

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

This just started happening today after I got a message from xcode to agree to new t&c's.

I can't put anything on the device, on any of my computers.

Doesn't work on my macbook, doesn't work on my mac mini, doens't work with existing projects that worked fine until yesterday, doesn't even work with completely new projects.
I constantly get the message:

> writeDictToFile:1241 open failed for
>   /Users/georgecook/Desktop/test/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/install-shadow-directory/339bee33bc83c8e05fbd004dcc732c0b/20715d40747e047ba8a4ce4c1d2672ef90161df5/ManifestCache.plist
>   : No such file or directory MDMCacheDirectoryManifest:1315
>   writeDictToFile failed to write to
>   /Users/georgecook/Desktop/test/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/install-shadow-directory/339bee33bc83c8e05fbd004dcc732c0b/20715d40747e047ba8a4ce4c1d2672ef90161df5/ManifestCache.plist
>   : No such file or directory error MT1006: Could not install the
>   application
>   '/Users/georgecook/Desktop/test/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/test.iOS.app' on
>   the device Gandalf the white: Your application failed code-signing
>   checks. Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle
>   ids. Probably your device is not part of the selected provisioning
>   profile (error: 0xe8008015).

No idea why this is suddenly happening - this is really not good - how to resolve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I tripped over this one recently too.

The key is this part of the message:

> Your application failed code-signing checks. Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle ids. Probably your device is not part of the selected provisioning profile

Likely, your provisioning profile has expired.   The easiest way to solve this is to launch Xcode, create an empty project, and hit Run.   This will go over a series of dialog boxes offering you to fix your provisioning profile until it deploys.   Once this happens, you can switch back to Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio and deploy.

Comment: such a pain...wasted like half a day on this in part because almost none of the instructions are clear.  try this:
Xcode / Preferences / Accounts / View Details / Download All (which refreshes all your certs).
Make sure you select the right Team Name, or do them all because who knows what else has expired.

Comment: I ran into this issue because my company email was tied to my personal account and my company account. I fixed by removing and re-adding accounts in visual studio (YourApp.IOS>Properies>Bundle Signing > Manage Accounts) and in XCode (Signing& Capabilities > Team). The Team guid updated to the correct one in VS after re-adding my account. I also had to erase existing apps from iphone.

Answer (score 6):

One reason this can happen is if you have multiple developer accounts set up in XCode. Here are the steps

1. Verify that your device is on Apple member center
2. Verify that your device is part of the relevant provisioning profile
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for each account
4. Create a new project in XCode and run it on the device. XCode may ask you to select the team (if you have multiple accounts)
5. If you have multiple developer accounts (teams) set up in XCode, the repeat step 4 each time with a new project and select a different team each time.

These steps ensure that XCode clears the way for Xamarin. The idea is that Xamarin does not allow you to decide which "team" to use, so you want to make sure that XCode has done the setup for EVERY team.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this `ManifestCache.plist : No such file or directory` problem. I checked device logs (`View -> Pads -> iOS Device Log`) to see why it was happening. Logs said it was rejecting an upgrade. Upgrade, I thought to myself, that doesn't sound right...then I remembered I had an app on my iPhone with the same identifier `to.dima.application` from a previous version which I forgot to uninstall. Removing the old app cleared up this issue for me. Hope this helps anyone else who has the same problem! :)

Answer (score 3):

It works! I have found the solution.I was facing the same problem. Somehow there was a misconfiguration in Xamarin. The **entitlements.plist** had a wrong manuel entry. The cert ist checking all the values in it and if you have a manuel entry there it is not working anymore. Apple is searching somehow only for own entry they are needing.

Comment: aps-environment - development or production in entitlements.plist

Answer (score 2):

I spent sometime on developer portal to find out the problem, it occurs because of distribution APNS or development. It did not fixed, after restoring all provisioning profiles and certificates, . In my case solution was letting Xamarin choose signing profiles. I did not use info.plist auto signing which did not solve either but **changing Project -> iOS Bundle Signing -> Signing identity, Provisioning Profile Auto** solved all issues for development and production cases.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and so I opened Xcode and updated all my profiles, but nothing happened. So I added the device UDID in the developer portal to the team I was developing for, went to Xcode and updated the profiles again, and then it worked. Don't know if the device must be registered to be able to build to device or this triggered some other update to my profiles that suddenly made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Today they published a new revision of the Apple Developer Licence agreement. 
The error message was essentially the same as OP's. The true reason only became apparent when creating a new project in XCode on the Mac, where more useful  warnings show up in the "Deployment info" section of the "General" tab.

I had to log in to apple.developer.com, there was a red panel asking me to accept the new licence conditions, and as soon as I did that, deploying apps from Xamarin immediately worked again.