# Problems with certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle ids. iOS development

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I have had many problems with certificates, provisioning profiles and bundle ids in the past and here is the latest.

When trying to run my App on an iOS device I get the following error:

> Your application failed code-signing checks. Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle ids. Probably your device is not part of the selected provisioning profile (error: 0xe8008015).

I am aware of the following questions that touch similar topics but I seem to have perhaps a combination of them with something else:

[Invalid Provisioning Profile- Missing Code-Signing Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697237/invalid-provisioning-profile-missing-code-signing-certificate)

[Xcode fails with “Code Signing” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962341/xcode-fails-with-code-signing-error)

[why does xamarin suddenly not let me deploy to iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319401/why-does-xamarin-suddenly-not-let-me-deploy-to-ios-devices)

[iOS 8, How to use device for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999167/ios-8-how-to-use-device-for-development)

In the past the following things fixed a similar type of error message, however, this time the error at most changed slightly:

1. Go to Apple Member center and check that the device I am using is listed under "iOS devices"
   [image]
2. Go to "Provisioning Profile" -> "Development" and check the profile is active [image]

3.Check the device is listed in the provisioning profile. Re-download the provisioning profile.

4.Clean and build the solution a lot.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using a macbook air running OSX 10.9.5 and iPad with iOS 8.2. 
Xamarin version 5.7.2
Xcode version 6.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was typing the last line of my question it occurred to me that I should check if my Xcode is up to date: It wasn't!

**Solution:**

1. **Updated Xcode to the latest version** (i.e. 6.2). In the update details it says: "Adds support for iOS 8.2 and WatchKit to create apps...".

While Xcode was updating I also did the following:

2. Correct a spelling mistake in my **bundle identifier (To be EXACTLY the same as in my provisioning profile)**.
3. In Apple member center I had the possibility to **update the list of devices**. This is since I renewed my licence not long ago and it gave me the option to reset my previous list. I just followed the instructions and left exactly the same devices as I had previously.
4. After X-code updated I **cleaned the solution** and DONE.

I had few things going on so perhaps this won't be really useful to anyone but who knows... I hope this helps